# Using https ssl url of Artifactory while connecting from Jfrog xray

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, artifactory, kubernetes-helm, jfrog-xray

I Just installed Jfrog Xray using Helm chart on our GKE cluster. 
The Artifactory Instance I want to connect to has SSL enabled (https://jfrog.<>/artifactory) and Xray is not able to connect to artifactory. I understand that artifactory cert needs to be installed on the Xray server container. 
My question is, should I directly install the certificate of artifactory and what is the process to do so. Also, if i'm using a different cert for Xray later, how can i install it on my server container

Appreciate the help

Thanks,
Krishna