# Jfrog Xray Certificate Issue

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-xray

Summary: 
Xray helm chart needs the capability to receive a custom certificate used for Artifactory and apply that certificate to the router container.

Detail:
We have successfully installed Artifactory via helm.  After installing, we configured TLS for the Artifactory web application using a custom certificate.  When trying to deploy Xray via helm, the xray server pod’s router container will continually fail to connect to Artifactory with an error message of

Error: Get https://[url redacted]/access/api/v1/system/ping: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

There does not appear to be any way to pass in a secret that would contain the custom certificate.  It looks like at this time the only option is to customize the helm chart to install the certificate in the container but that will put us out if sync with Jfrog to receive vulnerability database updates or any other updates x-ray request from Jfrog.

Edit - Someone is having the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59939631/using-https-ssl-url-of-artifactory-while-connecting-from-jfrog-xray/61686448#61686448). Can Xray even do what we are trying to do then?

Update from Jfrog Support:

With regards to the query on adding/importing the CA cert chain to Xray, we already have a Jira for the same and our team is currently woking on it. As a work around I would request you to mount a custom volume with the ssl cert. Then run the command to import the ssl cert to the cacerts file from the init container. 
Work around :
Create a Kubernetes configMap, and add the root and subordinate CA, and then mount that into the xray-server at /usr/local/share/ca-certificates. I then log into the server, and do a docker exec -it -u root into the xray server (since the container runs as a non-root user) and then run the command update-ca-certificates to import the CA certs.  Once you did this, then Xray will be able to talk to Artifactory. 
The drawback of this workaround would be we need to run the above steps every time the container restarts.

Comment: UPDATE: Had Jfrog support get back to us: